# Overlap 2 DIVs to show colour mix

Tags: css, html, webkit, overlap

Is it possible to see an overlap of these 2 DIVs to show like this [image] ?

```
<div style="position:relative;margin-top:100px;width:500px;height:300px;">
    <div style="background-color:rgba(23, 170, 180, 1);width:60px;height:145px;position:absolute;"></div>
    <div style="background-color:rgba(249, 177, 67, 1);width:110px;height:70px;position:absolute;"></div>        
</div>
```

Even if it works using only latest CSS3 or even -webkit- properties.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276859/are-photoshop-like-blend-modes-possible-in-html5

Comment: If I change the alpha value of both the DIVs, the non-overlapped parts also gets the opacity which I don't want.

Comment: Are you going to have anything other than colour in these divs?

Comment: Nope. These are just going to be colour boxes.

Comment: Could you not just add a third div and then use something like this to set the colour: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-color-plugin-xcolor/

Comment: I was hoping for a CSS3, -webkit- solution and not a JS one.

Comment: ok how about the third div with just a background colour set: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/RDwmQ/2/

Answer (score 0):

You've almost got it there, you just need to set an opacity to the overlaying div. You're already using `rgba()` color values, just the last unit `1` should be set to something lower than one:

```
#parent {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:100px;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
}

#one {
    background-color:rgba(23, 170, 180, 1);
    width:60px;
    height:145px;
    position:absolute;
}

#two {
    background-color:rgba(249, 177, 67, 0.5);
    width:110px;
    height:70px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VAWPK/

---

After reading your comments and seeing that you don't want the non overlapped parts of the divs to be affected by alpha values or opacity, you're going to have to look into `<canvas>/javascript` plugins like the one Nathan Lee linked to.

Answer (score 0):

try this i hope this will help for you

```
<div style="position:relative;margin-top:100px;width:500px;height:300px;">
    <div style="background-color:rgba(23, 170, 180, 1);width:60px;height:145px;position:absolute; z-index: 1;
opacity: 0.5; left: 25px;"></div>
    <div style="background-color:rgba(249, 177, 67, 1);width:110px;height:70px;position:absolute;"></div>        
</div>
```

see this http://jsfiddle.net/xu8n5/1/

Comment: set opacity according to your requirement

Comment: But I don't want the opacity of the non-overlapped parts to change.